# 2 forms in Jquery slider problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have two different forms in a Jquery slider (i am using this Jquery slider: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FancySlidingForm/) .

Now I would like to create javascript/jquery validation for these two forms **seperately** DEPENDING on which form the user selects (the user can select a form by using the buttons at the bottom) Just to make things easier, the form are using different names and ID's... Now if i do javascript validation on the samer page for the two forms, if the user selects a form and leaves the other one empty, an error is going to occur because of the validation created for the two form..I need to use something similar to onfocus i think so if a user selects a form, only ONE validation works.. Any help please? thanks

@kyushiro I would like to use something like the below for the validation please

```
           <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function DownloadValidate() {
    if (document.DownloadForm.txtFirstName.value == '' || document.DownloadForm.txtLastName.value == '' || document.DownloadForm.txtCompany.value == '' || document.DownloadForm.txtEmail.value == '' || document.DownloadForm.txtPhone.value == '' || document.DownloadForm.txtZipCode.value == '' || document.DownloadForm.cmbCountries.value == '') {
        alert('Please fill in all required fields');
        return false;
    }

    if (document.DownloadForm.cmbCountries.value == 'United States' && document.DownloadForm.cmbState.value == '') {
        window.alert('Please select your state')
        return false
    }

    var filter = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i
    if (filter.test(document.DownloadForm.txtEmail.value) == false) {
        window.alert('Please enter a valid email address')
        return false
    }

    DownloadForm.jsEnabled.value = 'true';
}
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you validating the form? using a plugin or by hand? if it is a jquery plugin make sure you call the validation on the specific form the user has selected  (ie for example `$('#form1').validate(etc);` rather than just `$('form').validate(etc);`

If you are doing it by hand it will depend on how you are triggering the validation. validating all fields in all forms on blur is a bad idea for example, and a better alternative would be to limit the scope of your validation function using again the specific form's id.

I think a code snippet showing how you perform the validation would be more useful in helping us to answer your question though :)

Comment: @ kyushiro can you please take a look at my edited post please? thanks

Comment: Could you add the 2 forms markup as well please? 
Anyways it seems that you are validating only your downloads form in this function. what is the other one?

I think the issue might be when you're triggering the actual validation. is that done in an onclick attribute? :)

Comment: ps. The validation can also be done via jquery itself since you've already included it for the slider plugin to work :)